# Nested ng-repeat not displaying the correct value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on a scenario where i am using nested ng-repeat to display the json values in html table.Attached the plunker plnkr.co/edit/qC6v8nOP4iFgjlxezTa1?p=preview.I am not able to see the last column values properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no problems with AngularJS, but with HTML, try [this variant](http://plnkr.co/edit/dYKP8q0kkp4ZgvRXqZFw?p=preview):

```
<table width="100%">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Id:</th>
     <th>Age:</th>
     <th>Subjects:</th>
     <th>Only Lecturer Name</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="x in student track by $index">
     <td>{{x.id}}</td>
     <td>{{x.age}}</td>
     <td>{{x.subjects}}</td>
     <td>
       <span ng-repeat="j in x.subjects">
         {{j.Lecturer}}
       </span>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```